# How to query this complex data? ITs nit just about the joins, I also need to understand how will the query work

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables, Bugs and BUgHistory.
Following data shoes their schema resepctively:

Bugs:

```
**BugId Priority Severity PlatformFound GameArea TestType**
-----------------------------------------------------------

23  0 - QA - Before Beta        Common      Ad Hoc Testing
46  0 - QA - Before Beta        Common      Ad Hoc Testing
69  0 - QA - Before Beta    C   Common  Art Ad Hoc Testing
92  0 - QA - Before Beta    B   Common  Audio   Ad Hoc Testing
138 1 - Dev - Medium        Playstation 4       Ad Hoc Testing
184 0 - QA - Before Beta    A   Common  Game Modes  Ad Hoc Testing
207 0 - QA - Before Beta    C   Common  Art Ad Hoc Testing
230 0 - QA - Before Beta    C   Common  Art Ad Hoc Testing
253 0 - QA - Before Beta        Common      Ad Hoc Testing
276 0 - QA - Before Beta    C   Common  Art Ad Hoc Testing
299 0 - QA - Before Beta    C   Playstation 4   Game Modes  Ad Hoc Testing
322 0 - QA - Before Beta    C   Common  Game Modes  Ad Hoc Testing
345 0 - QA - Before Beta    NULL    Common  NULL    Ad Hoc Testing
368 0 - QA - Before Beta    C   Common  Art Ad Hoc Testing
391 0 - QA - Before Beta        Common      Free Testing
414 0 - QA - Before Beta    C   Common  Game Modes  Free Testing
437 0 - QA - Before Beta    C   Common  Art Ad Hoc Testing
460 0 - QA - Before Beta    C   Common  Game Modes  Ad Hoc Testing
483 0 - QA - Before Beta    C   Common  Art Ad Hoc Testing
```

BugHistory:

```
BugId   FullDate      ProgressStatus
23     2016-11-29   Submitted
23     2016-11-30   Submitted
23     2016-12-01   Submitted
23     2016-12-02   Submitted
23     2016-12-03   Submitted
23     2016-12-04   Submitted
46     2017-07-17   Closed - Fixed
46     2017-07-18   Closed - Fixed
46     2017-07-19   Closed - Fixed
46     2017-07-20   Closed - Fixed
46     2017-07-21   Closed - Fixed
46     2017-07-22   Closed - Fixed
46     2017-07-23   Closed - Fixed
69     2016-11-29   Submitted
69     2016-11-30   Submitted
69     2016-12-01   Submitted
69     2016-12-02   Submitted
```

I need to Create a SQL query to merge the data from ‘BugHistory’ and ‘Bugs’ so that I get the count of severity-A Bugs for each ‘FullDate’. Include only days with a count of more than 7 bugs in the results.

And this is my query:

```
SELECT count(bugs.BugID), bughistory.fullDate severity_A FROM 'Bugs' bugs
INNER JOIN 'BugHistory' bughistory ON bugs.BugID = bughistory.BugId where bugs.Severity = 'A' 
GROUP BY(bughistory.FullDate) Having count(bugs.BugID) > 7;
```

Comment: I am thinking of an Inner join of the tables.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using ? Please dont spam tag all the RDBMS !

Comment: Is there any reason for the `R` tag? Since the question doesn't mention R I'm removing it.

Comment: I am using MySQL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Hi Madhur, I posted my query above.

Comment: @Brett please post the expected output in tabular manner, as per your given sample data.

Comment: I don't know what the expected output should look like. 
I need the count of severity-A Bugs for each ‘FullDate’ Including only days with a count of more than 7 bugs in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `INNER JOIN` between the two tables using `BugId` and `Severity = 'A'`. We can then `GROUP BY` on `FullDate` and `Count(Distinct ..)` can be used to count unique Bugs on a particular date.

Eventually, `HAVING` clause will consider only those dates, where bugs are more than or equal to 7.

```
SELECT 
  bh.FullDate, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT bh.BugId) AS total_bugs 
FROM BugHistory AS bh 
JOIN Bugs AS b 
  ON b.BugId = bh.BugId AND 
     b.Severity = 'A'
GROUP BY bh.FullDate 
HAVING total_bugs >= 7
```

Comment: Thanks, Madhur!
I am just wondering, do we need ```DISTINCT``` clause.

Comment: @Brett to count **unique** bugs only. There is a possibility that same bug may have multiple entries on same date. If your application ensures that for a bug, only one entry can happen at max; then you can get rid of `distinct`.

Comment: Yes, there can only be one bug and hence I didn't use distinct in my query as well. I am glad that you helped me and also happy about the fact that I got the correct answer myself as well because both queries are giving the same answer.
But, Thanks for being so helpful!

Comment: @Brett happy to help. :)

Comment: I have one more question
I need a SQL query that shows the count of open bugs for each ‘GameArea’ and ‘FullDate’.

Comment: @Brett you can do multiple level Group by. So do `Group By FullDate and GameArea`; in the join condition consider only those bugs which are open and then count them

Comment: I wrote this:
```SELECT count(*) Open_Bugs, bugs.GameArea, bugHistory.fullDate FROM     `Bugs` bugs FULL JOIN `BugHistory` bughistory ON bugs.BugId = bughistory.BugId
where bugs.ProgressStatus in ('Open', 'Assigned')
group by GameArea, fullDate```

Comment: @Brett looks fine

Comment: Hi, Madhur! I have very less experience with Data Visualization.
Can you guide me what to do, as the Question says " using a program of your choice, provide a visualization of the Open Bugs that shows the number of open bugs for each ‘FullDate’ broken down by ‘GameArea’.